# Calculate the solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Calculate the solution of the differential equation:

$t^2\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2t\frac{dx}{dt}-6x=t^3,\:\:with\:x\left(1\right)=0,\:x\left(2\right)=\frac{21}{16}$

Hope someone can explain to me how to solve it step by step from the begging

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve it thus far?

Comment: I couldn't do anything about it

Answer (score 1):

Start with the substitution 
$$
x(t) = t^r
$$

Plug this into the non-homogenous ODE and see where you can go from there.

After this substitution, your ODE becomes the following:

$$
r(r-1)t^r + 2rt^r - 6t^r = t^3
$$

Do some algebra, and get the characteristic polynomial.  Solve the homogenous case and non homogenous case separately.  Use initial conditions to find the constants, and then have a good day!  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Solve the homogeneous equation first. Make the substitution $t = e^u$ to get an equation with constant coefficients on $\frac{dx}{du}$ and $\frac{d^2 x}{du^2}$. Solve it. Then go back to $t$. Do a quick search on Euler's equation.

Comment: I really don't know how to start it and didn't understand what you mean, can u please explain further how to start and what to do step by step?

Comment: The homogeneous equation is when the RHS is zero. An equation with constant coefficients can be solved using its characteristic polynomial. The first step to do I already told you..